# C# Lambda expressions and NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lambda

I'm a newbie in the great world of NHibernate. I'm using version 2.0.1.GA. Here's my question. I have a table `Cars` with column `Manufacturer(nvarchar(50))` and a primary key `ID(int)`. My .NET class is:

```
public class Car
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I want to retrieve all cars made by Mercedes I have to type this:

```
using (var session = OpenSession())
{
    var cars = session
        .CreateCriteria(typeof(Car))
        .Add(Restrictions.Like("Manufacturer", "Mercedes"))
        .List();
    // ...
}
```

I don't like the fact that I need to specify the property name as a string :(
Is it possible to have something more refactor friendly probably (it's only a suggestion)?

```
var ms = session
    .CreateCriteria<Car>()
    .Add(c => c.Manufacturer, Restrictions.Like("Mercedes")
    .List();
```

Anything like thins in the current version (2.0.1.GA) or in a future version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Google Ninja said, you can do it with NHibernate.Linq.
The query would then be:

`session.Linq<Car>.Where(c => c.Manufacturer == "Mercedes").ToList()`

If someone ends up here and is using NH3.0 the syntax is just a tad different (thanks to  Michael Mrozek and Mike for the suggestion):

`session.Query<Car>.Where(c => c.Manufacturer == "Mercedes").ToList()`

I've used a binary that came bundled with [fluent-nhibernate](http://code.google.com/p/fluent-nhibernate/) that works with 2.0GA (I think, not sure about the particular revision).

Comment: Thanks, didn't have the syntax off the top of my head, +1

Comment: I might observe that "like" and "equals" will not produce the same results.  I recently tried (not very hard) to find a way to do "like" in NHibnate.Linq.  I gave up and used ICriteria instead.

Comment: In a suggested edit [Mike](http://stackoverflow.com/users/77939/mike) pointed out that "If you are using NHibernate 3.0 or later, the LINQ provider is built in. The usage is only slightly different: `session.Query<Car>.Where(c => c.Manufacturer == "Mercedes").ToList()`"

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use Linq to NHibernate yet, there's a couple of alternatives to get strongly type Criteria queries:

- http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2008/03/strongly-typed-nhibernate-criteria-with.html
- http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2008/08/17/what-would-nhibernate-icriteria-look-like-in-.net-3.5.aspx

Comment: Fast-forward to 2011: LINQ is now integrated into NHibernate, and there's also the QueryOver API.

Answer (score 4):

You could probably do this with NHibernate.Linq. It is in a usable form, but still a ways from being complete. Its currently living inside nhcontrib, the only way to get it is to pull it out of svn here https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Linq/

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299384/linq-to-nhibernate-project-status-contributing-lead). Someone had the same worry, and from I can gather, NHibernate.Linq is well alive.

Answer (score 1):

You can find what you are looking for [here (blog entry)](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/01/07/typesafe-icriteria-using-lambda-expressions.aspx) or [here (google repository)](http://code.google.com/p/nhlambdaextensions/)