# Strongly typed properties with NHIbernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NHibernate in my project, but I dont like to use typed properties for selecting items from database. 
Is it possible to have instead of

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(IEntry)).AddOrder(Order.Desc("Alias"))
```

somthing like this

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(IEntry)).AddOrder(Order.Desc(x=>x.Alias))
```

Thanks,
Alexander.

---

I tried to use NHibernate.Link, but I can't use because it has no strong name :( Will wait for next version and continue to use my solution now

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341239/c-lambda-expressions-and-nhibernate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With NH 2 you could use  the [nh lambda extensions](http://code.google.com/p/nhlambdaextensions/)

```
list = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat))
    .Add<Cat>( c => c.Age >= 2 && c.Age <= 8 )
    .AddOrder<Cat>( c => c.Name, Order.Desc )
    .List<Cat>();
```

In NH 3, you would use [QueryOver](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx)

```
list = session.QueryOver<Cat>()
    .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.Age).IsBetween(2).And(8)
    .OrderBy(c => c.Name).Desc
    .List<Cat>();
```

Or you could use NHibernate.Linq

```
list = (from c in session.Linq<Cat>()
    where c.Age >= 2 && c.Age <= 8
    orderby c.Name descending
    select c).ToList<Cat>();
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the nh lambda extensions project!

Answer (score 2):

In the NHibernate trunk (3.0 version) are two ways:

- Query over, the new criteria api
  [example](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/06/criteria-on-nh300.html)
- Linq

Answer (score 1):

Here you are: [Strongly typed NHibernate Criteria with C# 3](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2008/03/strongly-typed-nhibernate-criteria-with.html)